# Adding new files to rsyslogd with wildcards

Tags: nginx, rsyslog, papertrail-app

We're got a pre-existing rsyslog config file which is working for papertrail e.g.

`/etc/rsyslog.d/20-papertrail.conf` which has

```
*.*          @logs4.papertrailapp.com:44407
```

However we've got a couple of NGINX websites on the server so would like to have it also monitor their error logs.

The paths to them are:

```
/var/log/nginx/www.website-one.com-error.log
/var/log/nginx/www.website-two.com-error.log
/var/log/nginx/www.website-three.com-error.log
```

However this `/var/log/nginx` also contains a bunch of `.log` files which we do not want to monitor e.g.

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log1
/var/log/nginx/nginx.log
```

In my head we need to add something like...

```
/var/log/nginx/*-error.log
```

And make sure they pipe to the papertrail url as well.

However I'm struggling to decipher the rsyslog documentation to figure out how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html)?, NGINX allows to use multiple access_log or error_log directives in each vhost

Answer (score 1):

In [rsyslog documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html) it seems that you can use wildcards in files.

## File

*The file being monitored. So far, this must be an absolute name (no macros or templates). Note that wildcards are supported at the file name level (see WildCards below for more details).*

## WildCards

### Before Version: 8.25.0

*Wildcards are only supported in the filename part, not in directory names.*

`/var/log/*.log` *works.*

`/var/log/*/syslog.log` *does not work.*

### Since Version: 8.25.0

*Wildcards are supported in filename and paths which means these samples will work:*

`/var/log/*.log` *works.*

`/var/log/*/syslog.log` *works.*

`/var/log/*/*.log` *works.*

*All matching files in all matching subfolders will work. Note that this may decrease performance in imfile depending on how many directories and files are being watched dynamically.*

If you want to forward your vhosts logs you can change configuration directly in NGINX vhosts configuration, you should change/add `access_log` and `error_log` policies as explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html) or use custom facilities to forward your logs (using rsyslog).

## HOW TO DO IT USING RSYSLOG?

Create a new custom file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/nginx_custom.conf`:

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="1") #needs to be done just once

# File 1
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/nginx/www.website-*.com-error.log"
      Tag="websites"
      Facility="local0")

local0.* @logs4.papertrailapp.com:44407
#Just to test that logs are forwarded, comment the line once you've tested it
local0.* /var/log/test.log
```

And restart rsyslog service

**NOTE**: Line `local0.* /var/log/test.log` is just to test that you can see forwarded logs into your local server, comment this line after you've tested that everything works.

Comment: Thanks for this, helpful and informative, will give it a go shortly!

Comment: @alvaro-niño Does it work with inotify module ? I selected /var/log/redis/*.log but it isending some random file /var/log/folder-A/radom.log ?

Comment: @alvaro-niño How do I sent only new logs with /var/log/myap/2022/*/*/*.log ? 20/*/*/ just month date which keeps changing